# Odd display formatting in jquery datepicker when increasing number of months

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datepicker

When I set the numberOfMonths parameter to something high (e.g. 6), the datepicker display looks weird in that the background extends much further than it should.  See my example jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/zw3z2vjh/

In the example, I'm forcing the number of months to be 6 using 1 row and 6 columns:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        showButtonPanel: false,
        numberOfMonths: [1,6],
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        maxDate: new Date(2014,08,11),
        minDate: new Date(2006, 0, 1)
    });
});
```

Any idea how I fix this so that the background fits properly?

Comment: You're talking about the leftover space to the far right?

Comment: Yeah.  The border just extends out way more than it needs to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what is going on with the datepicker, but the fix is easy enough.  Set a width on "#datepicker .ui-date-picker".

```
#datepicker .ui-date-picker {
    width: 75em !important;
}
```

Check out this fiddle I forked from yours:
http://jsfiddle.net/j5t52kke/